# Busy waiting and context switch

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

If I have two processes, why busy waiting avoids the context switch ? And why context switch is less expensive than wasting CPU time in this scenario ? What changes if there are threads instead of processes ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why busy waiting avoids the context switch

Busy waiting **doesn't** avoid context switch! context switch is the process in which the scheduler decides to give the CPU to other process to run. Busy waiting is a technique used to keep a process looping and waiting for something. i.e. to prevent two processes from modifying some shared data at the same time. One process will loop until the other process "tell" him it has finished. This is a bad synchronization method as CPU utilization drops as process spends its time burst doing nothing.

> And why context switch is less expensive than wasting CPU time

**DEPENDS!** if the code in critical section is short, busy waiting might be faster than a context switch. A process can ignore signals and by this way run on CPU until it gives it away voluntarily. **NOTE** not all signals can be ignored.

> What changes if there are threads instead of processes ?

I am afraid this is too board to answer as this might depend on OS and if OS is aware of threads.

Comment: I have only one issue with your answear, busy waiting is not a bad synchronization method, it depends on the use case. Sometimes when the event does not take too long it is better to use busy waiting instead of kernel events, as there would be too much overhead introduced by kernel objects and if you know the event (or signalling) will be in a very short time busy waiting is in fact a better approach, switching between user mode and kernel mode may be an overkill if the time spent while busy waiting is smaller than this overhead.

Comment: @EduG indeed. And I've mentioned it in my answer. Sometimes a busy waiting might be better than going through a context switch.